# If NOT ActiveSheet.Range() Is Nothing keeps erroring out when it finds nothing

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sub that reads a text file and imports data to a Defined Name cell. There is some data in the text file i don't need, so if the sub cannot find a matching cell it is just suppose to ignore it.

But, when the function finds a Defined Name that doesn't exist it throws an 1004 error. Putting `On Error Resume Next` after the `Do While Not` fixes the problem, but that is more of a band-aid solution.

Here is the function that is throwing the error:

```
If Not ActiveSheet.Range(cellName) Is Nothing Then
    Set TxtRng = ActiveSheet.Range(cellName)

    If TxtRng = ActiveSheet.Range(cellName) Then
        TxtRng.Value = getPrice
    End If
End If
```

I have also tried this version of the function, and it still causes a 1004 error:

```
If ActiveSheet.Range(cellName) Is Nothing Then
    ''Do Nothing here
Else
    Set TxtRng = ActiveSheet.Range(cellName)

    If TxtRng = ActiveSheet.Range(cellName) Then
        TxtRng.Value = getPrice
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Use ***OnError***

Comment: Trying to refer to a non-existent named range doesn't return Nothing, it causes a run time error. So use error handling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use error handling because trying to use a non existent range name throws an error.

```
Dim TxtRng As Range

Set TxtRng = Nothing 'if you use this code in a loop make sure you initialize it as nothing within your loop. Otherwise you can omit this line.

On Error Resume Next
Set TxtRng = ActiveSheet.Range(cellName)
On Error Goto 0 're-activate error reporting

If Not TxtRng Is Nothing Then
    'your code
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this did the trick.Do you know off hand of any good tutorials on error handling?

Comment: @Geoffrey Here is a pretty complete one: [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)